# Why do we Softmax at all?

Tags: neural-network, classification, multiclass-classification

Why take softmax at all at the final layer for multi-class classification problems? For example softmax of the vector [1, .5]

Is [.621, .379]

I mean if we just took the straight ratio, it'd give me
[.667, .333] instead

Does that really make a difference?

Is it cause the vector can have negative numbers that we softmax things? What benefit do we get from making an odder way to give a ratio/probability to certain numbers as opposed to just taking a ratio of the numbers?

Comment: Softmax is exactly that ratio, but the differentiable one.

Comment: Could I ask for more elaboration? From what I know, the ratio function is also differentiable

Comment: For example you can find the derivative of  xi/summation(xvec) by using the quotient rule

Comment: The point is that ratio, maps $R^n$ to $R^1$ while you need a function that maps all the outputs to their corresponding ratio. This is done using softmax which is a mapping from $R^n$ to $R^n$.

Comment: But for example the ratio of [1,.5] maps to [.667,.333], am i missing something here?

Comment: Yes, you are finding softmax not ratio.

Comment: Wouldnt the softmax be [.621, .379] and not [.667, .333]?

Comment: Oops, you are referring to something else that I didn't notice. The point is that in the last layer you may have `tanh` activation function which may lead to negative outcomes. This will affect the simple sum which is going to be in the denominator. Consequently, we use exponentiation to avoid wrong ratios. Due to the fact that they should be valid probabilities.

Comment: That might be a reason. But also can happen without tanh by using negative weights. I think there might be more to why someone decided to use the craxy softmax formula, instead of other formulas that can handle negative vals. Have an upvote for the input :p

Comment: It depends, if you use `Relu` or `Softmax` nonlinarities you won't have any negative value, but using `leaky-relu` may also lead to that.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187507/why-use-softmax-as-opposed-to-standard-normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio doesn't take into account the fact that the last layer may have negatives results, in which case the ratio doesn't work, while the `softmax` does. Another corner case is if the denominator of the ratio is zero.

Also, softmax has two interesting properties:

1. It will accentuate the differences between the input and the output, by squashing the lower values and increasing the highest value, which makes the output of the network closert to a `max` instead of a `softmax` (note that `max` is not differentiable and hence cannot be used).
2. In a classification problem, where a `softmax` layer is used, the loss function is the cross entropy, which has the form `- y * log(y_hat)`. Turns out that `log` of `softmax` is very easy to compute, as `log(a/b)` is `log(a) - log(b)` and `log(exp(x))` is simply `x`. That makes `softmax` more desired.

Comment: Everything is good, but i have a question. Why is max not differentiable?

Comment: With an example: `max([4,3,2])` will be 4. That operation can be understand as: multiply by 1 the element where there is the maximum (4) otherwise by zero, and sum the result. Implicitly one is multiplying by the step function, which is not differentiable.

Comment: Excellent, i love upvoting posts like these. Btw rereading your post again on "Turns out that log of softmax is very easy to compute, as log(a/b) is log(a) - log(b) and log(exp(x)) is simply x. That makes softmax more desired." Did you simply mean to say its fast to compute this? If so, can you apply the same division becoming subtraction for log(exp(x1)/(exp(x1) +exp(x2))? Which is just a softmax of two classes